# How to check password which is encoded?

Tags: php, symfony, hash, encode, bcrypt

Sign Up:

```
$users->setSalt(md5(time()));
$encoder = new MessageDigestPasswordEncoder('sha1', true, 1);
$password = $encoder->encodePassword($users->getPassword(), $users->getSalt());
$users->setPassword($password);
```

The result is something like this: qSmJxDmP8WhVJZIiJpeVLJFLnio=
So, the password is safe. But how to check is it the same password when the user try to login?
(password came from the form is it equals to password in database)

I'm confused because there have salt, which is every time unique.
What is better technique?

Comment: I guess you need to store the salt to the DB and then when user logs in get the record using the username and reconstruct the password usign the same salt. This reconstructed password should match the stored password ?

Comment: You better read [Security -> Users](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#users) section..

Answer (score 1):

@Deepak's comment is correct. Salt is **not** meant to be unique on every request. It is meant to be unique universally, and assigned quasi-permanently to the user's account.

You store the same salt value that was used to create the password hash when the password was set.

Then when you check the password supplied by the user, you use the same salt value, compute a new hash, and compare that to the stored hash. If they match, you have a winner.

Comment: I understood the sense. Thank you for this posting.

Answer (score -1):

Your passwords are stored as salts, no?

session_start();

Have a logIn() function to verify every secure action with a logOut(), query your DB by username from either $_POST['username'] or $_SESSION['username']

```
$user = DB_QUERY_BY_USERNAME;

if ( !$user ) { logOut(); }

if ( $_POST['username'] && $_POST['password'] )
{
    if ( $user['password'] != md5( $_POST['password'] . $user['salt'] ) )
    {
        logOut();
    }
}
else if ( $_SESSION['username'] != $user['username'] )
{
    logOut();
}

// Logged in, renew cookies, update DB, set $_SESSION variables

$_SESSION['username'] = $user['username'];
```

Comment: Passwords are not *"stored as salts."* You store a hash of your password *plus* the salt. Your code sample looks generally ok, except that md5 is woefully inadequate these days. "Salt" is just a nickname for random bits that are appended to a password before hashing, in order to guarantee that every resulting password hash is unique. You store the salt along with the hash, never storing the actual password. If you combine the salt and password and hash that value the same way the stored hash was generated, and the computed hash matches the stored hash, then the correct password was supplied.

Comment: Downvoted for suggesting weak/compromised straight md5 algorithm instead of pbkdf2, bcrypt, scrypt or at least an HMAC algorithm with SHA256 (because SHA1 is at least theoretically broken now, too), and also for suggesting logging the user out and logging them back in on every page request.